# Given a differential form $\omega$, is there a differential form $\phi$ such that $\omega\wedge\phi$ is closed?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, closed-form, vector-bundles, exterior-derivative

Let $M$ be a differential manifold and $\Omega^p(M)$ the vector bundle
of $p$-forms. My question is:

**Given a differential $p$-form $\omega$, is there a differential $q$-form $\phi$ such that $d(\omega\wedge\phi)=0$?**

I am excluding the trivial cases when $\omega$ is already closed or when $(q+p)$ is larger or equal to the dimension of the cotangent space at a point.

My question is a generalization of the [integrating factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrating_factor) problem, where $\omega$ is a 1-form, $\phi$ is a function and $d(f\omega)$ should be *exact* and not only closed as I am requiring. In [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/227799/existance-of-integrating-factors-a-constructive-proof) question about the existence of integrating factor for 1-forms in two variables the answers say that the problem is difficult and still open, even in this simpler case.

I was unable to find any reference who could be of some help in answer my question, then I would really appreciate if someone can give me some directions in the literature and, if possible, discuss some special cases
where a solution is or is not possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a) If $\omega\in\Omega^{p}(M)$ for $p$ odd, then $\omega\wedge\omega=0$, so certainly $d(\omega\wedge\omega)=0$.

b) If $\omega\in\Omega^{p}(M)$ for $p$ even, then $d(\omega\wedge d\omega)=d\omega\wedge d\omega=0$.

Comment: Great! But I am feeling dumb...  It seems that my "generalization" is trivial and not harder than the original problem for the integrating factor. Thank you!